# Calculate column based on maximum value from another table with 1:n relation

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, one-to-many, calculated-columns

I have two tables linked via a foreign key:

```cs
    class Account {
        [KEY]
        Guid ID { get; set; }

        // calculated from highest record in Role table with same ID
        int HighestRole { get; set; } 

        [ForeignKey("ID")]
        ICollection<R> Roles { get; set; }
    }


    class Role {
        [KEY]
        Guid ID { get; set; }

        int RoleID { get; set; }
    }
```

An account can have several roles. For each account record, I want to calculate the highest role from the Role table. However, I have no clue how the SQL for that has to look. I googled and experimented for a while, but to no avail.

I tried

```
select 
    ID,
    (select MAX(RoleID) from Roles where Roles.ID = ID)
from Accounts
```

But this return the highest role id from all role ids in the Roles tables instead the highest role id related to a given record from the Accounts table (i.e. highest RoleID value is 2, some users have highest RoleID 1, but the query result yields 2 for each and every user).

How do I have to write this down in SQL please?

Comment: this seems C# to me, if that's the case, can you get it from the Roles collection? maybe using linq? something like: 
int HighestRole { get { return Roles.Max(r => r.RoleID); } }

Comment: In SQL you can just use a GROUP BY e.g., `SELECT ID, MAX(RoleID) AS MaxRole FROM Role GROUP BY ID`

Comment: I need a calculated column which contains the highest role of each user. Not sure your propositions work for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your SQL query:

```
select MAX(RoleID) from Roles where Roles.ID = ID
```

The WHERE is compared the ID from the `Roles` table to the `Roles.ID` which is the exact same column.  Thus, it'll always return the highest `Roles.ID`

That query can be fixed by aliasing the outer query:

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    (SELECT MAX(R.RoleID) FROM Roles R WHERERoles.ID = A.ID)
FROMAccounts A
```

You could also try doing an `INNER JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    MAX(R.RoleID)
FROM Accounts A
JOIN Roles R ON R.ID = A.ID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

This statement wouldn't return rows that don't have at least one matching record in Roles.  If you did want those, change this to a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Avogrado: Thanks, that helped me a long way. One question: How would I handle R.RoleID being null? In that case, I would want a default value to be used instead.

Comment: Use a `CASE WHEN MAX(R.RoleID) IS NULL THEN _DEFAULT_VALUE_ ELSE MAX(R.RoleID)` to help with null values.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff if you feel this was the correct answer for your question please take a second to accept it :)